# Como ter uma ArrayList por composição

Tags: java, arraylist, composição

Entendo como fazer composição mas nunca fiz com listas, embora o principio deve ser o mesmo, não estou a entender como fazer.

Para começar eu tenho uma classe `CentroComercial` que possui uma `ArrayList` chamada `lojas` que passará por atributo no `construtor`.

`Lojas`é uma `ArrayList` que armazena objetos do tipo `Loja`. estando esta super-classe dividida em várias subclasses. E estou com duas dúvidas.

1. Como devo fazer o

   ```
   public void setLojas(ArrayList<Loja> lojas) {}
   ```
2. qual é a melhor maneira de instânciar o Arraylist?

`private ArrayList<Loja> lojas;`

`private ArrayList<Loja> lojas = new ArrayList<Loja>();`

ou doutra forma até?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o método que vai ter é esse

```
public void setLojas(ArrayList<Loja> lojas) {}
```

Então bastará declarar o ArrayList assim

```
private ArrayList<Loja> lojas;
```

No entanto, se quer garantir que tem um objecto válido `loja` de forma a evitar possíveis NullPointerException use:

```
private ArrayList<Loja> lojas = new ArrayList<Loja>();
```

Essa é a forma preferível já que permite identificar/indicar de forma segura quando o CentroComercial não tem lojas associadas(pode usar `lojas.size()`).

O método `setLojas()` será assim

```
public void setLojas(ArrayList<Loja> lojas){
    this.lojas = lojas;
}
```

Se quer que não seja possível alterar externamente o ArrayList guardado, crie uma nova instância.

```
public void setLojas(ArrayList<Loja> lojas){
    lojas = new ArrayList<Loja>(lojas);
}
```

Se tiver um método *get* este deverá também retornar uma nova instância

```
public ArrayList<Loja> getLojas(){
    return new ArrayList<Loja>(lojas);
}
```

O objecto `loja` também deverá ser imutável.

Comment: mas isso garante que lojas estão por composição? eu modificando `lojas`, não mudo a lista de `lojas` em qualquer instância de `CentroComercial` que tenha essa lista?

Comment: Tem de explicar melhor o que pretende. Para que não seja possível modificar o ArrayList `lojas` ele terá de ser passado ao construtor e o método `setLojas()` não poderá existir. Se for isso diga que eu acrescento à resposta.

Comment: O ArrayList pode e tem de estar no construtor, é um atributo de `CentroComercial` mas tem de estar implementado por composição. de modo a que se eu modificar de qualquer maneira a lista noutra classe, qualquer instância de `CentroComercial` não tenha alterado a lista dele. este é o código que tenho e estou com dúvidas. https://snag.gy/ifSbpP.jpg

Comment: Agora entendi. Julgo que a sua implementação está correta já que guarda uma nova instância e retorna também uma nova instância. Apenas tem de garantir que um objecto `loja` seja também imutável.

Comment: Aquele construtor que aceita um CentroComercial seria talvez preferível substitui-lo por uma implementação do método `clone()`